# How to calculate the weights in a Sankey chart?

Tags: highcharts

I am considering using a Sankey chart but I fail to clearly understand how to calculate the weights.

Let's assume a case where an entity (`one`) is split into `hello` and `world`, at respectively 70% and 30%.

`hello` is then split into `aaa` and `bbb`, also 70/30.

From the documentation I thought that the weights were relative to the output node (code also in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WoJWoJ/3zdetvoy/) and [CodePen](https://codepen.io/WoJWoJ/pen/dKQZRa) -- for some reason the same code refuses to run in the SO snippet below):

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
 series: [{
        keys: ['from', 'to', 'weight'],
        data: [
            ['One', 'hello', 70],
            ['One', 'world', 30],
            ['hello', 'aaa', 70],
            ['hello', 'bbb', 30],

        ],
        type: 'sankey', 
    }]
});
```

```css
#container {
    min-width: 300px;
    max-width: 800px;
    height: 400px;
    margin: 1em auto;
    border: 1px solid silver;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/sankey.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

This is not the case, however: both `world` and `bbb` have the same size, namely `30`.

This means that the weights are absolute: in my case I need to take `100` and distribute it accordingly between `world` (30), `aaa` (70*0.7 = 49) and `bbb` (70*0.3 = 21).

**If so, where should I put `world` as it is auto-calculated from the other data?** (it is an "intermediate" result)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally worked out the numbers. The key is to use absolute numbers, but compute them for every step.

In the example of my question that would be:

- `one`: 100 (fixed)
- `world`: 30 (fixed)
- `hello`: 70 (fixed)
- `aaa`: 49 (calculated 70*0.7 = 49)
- `bbb`: 21 (calculated 70*0.3 = 21)

This leads to the [following code](https://codepen.io/WoJWoJ/pen/vrQaBQ).